# Running a New Telephone Wire For Master Socket - Cross Over Electrical Cables

Tags: electrical, telephone

I have moved into a property that was built in the 1930's so the walls are double wall cavity and also inside the house its all rock solid brick.

This causes me an issue whereby the Master Telephone Socket is in my hallway right in the middle of the walkway so at present my Sky Q Router sits on its side on the floor, obviously this causes an issue both for it getting kicked over and a trip hazard.

I've decided to wire in a new master socket behind my tv in the living room (I know BT would have issue with this). My question is my cable goes out of my living room wall into my garage the intention is to travel down my internal garage wall but it would pass my Electrical Meter located in the garage also (including my fuse box etc.).

My query is this am I going to affect my line quality by crossing my new telephone cable over my electrical cables? I understand my telephone line is low voltage and it isn't wise to run it in tandem next to electrical wire however I am just 'crossing-over' to get outside the property to get to the IDC Junction Box that connects my telephone pole wire to the house.

Sorry for the essay but thought it best to give all the facts.

Answer (score 3):

Crossing power lines at a 90 will have no affects on the phone or data quality on the low voltage system.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in every phone company central office, the dsl wires and the POTs lines with 100vac ringing on them and analog voice are laying on top of each other in the racks and the same 100vac ringing on POTs lines run parallel next to dsl wires for many miles inside those huge phone lines you see on the poles without causing problems.